# Reference variables as arguments for functions and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, reference, stdvector

I have a function which I want to pass a reference to a vector as an argument.

```
void function(std::vector<double>& datavector)
{
}
```

The man function looks like this:

```
int main(int argn, char** argv)
{
    // Create a vector containing 12 variables
    std::vector<double> data;
    for(uint32_t i = 0x0; i < 0xC; i ++) data.push_back(i % 0x3);

    // Using two threads
    std::vector<std::thread> thread;
    std::vector<double> result;
    result.push_back(0.0);

    thread.push_back(std::thread(function, data));
    thread.push_back(std::thread(function, data));

    // OOPS! Should have thread.join!
    thread[0].join();
    thread[1].join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But when I try to compile I get this error:

```
no type named 'type' in class std::result_of<void (*(std::vector<double>))(std::vector<double>&)>
```

I am guessing this means I am not allowed to pass a reference to a vector as an argument in my function. Is there a solution to this problem? Can I pass a pointer instead?

Comment: Edited to include thread.join() - Probably need that!

Comment: There are also missing parentheses when you do `push_back()`

Comment: I am guessing you need `std::ref`.

Comment: @AndyProwl, sorry I'll change it

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, What is that?

Comment: See note here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread. It marks as argument as being pass-by-ref. The default in `std::thread`, `std::bind`, etc, is pass-by-value.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::ref instead

Chage:

```
thread.push_back(std::thread(function, data));
```

to:

```
thread.push_back(std::thread(function, std::ref(data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a pointer instead. But this doesn't answer the question of why a reference variable isn't allowed.

Change:

```
std::vector<double>&
```

To:

```
std::vector<double>*
```

Not a perfect solution since dereferencing is required.